# GWT UiBinder new import in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, uibinder, google-plugin-eclipse

I use Eclipse with GWT plugin. When I create new UIBinder 
Simple.ui.xml:

```
ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:b='urn:import:org.mycomp.ui'
```

new import was added org.mycomp.ui (my own component represented by jar). But Eclipse editor marks it as error (Simple.ui.xml) - *Package org.mycomp.ui cannot be resolved*

Where in project properties can I add my jar with org.mycomp.ui to make it visible for Eclipse?

Comment: It *could* be that this package is not in the "client path" of a GWT module.

Comment: Where i can modify this path?

Comment: When i try to build module then got error  com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: ( )......  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source).   So on ECLIPSE GWT Plugin can'nt parse my import :  urn:import:org.mycomp.ui  .  But if i build project by maven gwt plugin is work fine

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`, select `Libraries` tab and use `Add JARs` or `Add External JARs`.

You can copy your jar to `war/WEB-INF/lib` and use `Add JARs` to point to that file or if you want to keep your jar outside your project use `Add External JARs`.